# Read a URL parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I read the value of ID with a url similar to the following?

```
http://intranet/page.aspx?id=10
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get QueryString values with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JQuery's URL parser plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/url_parser).

Answer (score 2):

```
function gup( name ) //stands for get url param
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}

var my_param = gup( 'id' );
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QYWUZ/) that uses a variable with a static url to test the output.  This is done without using jQuery, however.

Answer (score 0):

http://7php.com/javascript-using-jquery-to-find-url-querystring-or-url-params-a-simple-yet-effective-approach/

That link helped me to do the same, has jQuery and JavaScript examples.

Comment: Hello! I didn't downvote either, but I'm willing to guess the downvote is because you posted a link only answer, and if this link were to ever break, your answer would be useless. To get more upvotes *and* make sure your post is useful to future visitors, consider making an [edit] to your post to add in the example from the link. Links are helpful, but the best answers are self-contained and future proof! Good luck! :)